# cornerRadius with border: Glitch around border

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

My application is mostly round- and borderbased.

I use the layer property of `UIView` to give a corner radius and a border.

But I am facing a problem that the corners are not clear.

I am getting the following results:

**UIButton**

[image: screenshot of a button with rounded corners and a border]

**UIImageView**

[image: screenshot of an image view with rounded corners and a border]

You can observe a thin border line around the white or grey border.

This is my code:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I have searched to solve this but I'm not getting success.

I have tried `button.layer.masksToBounds = YES`, but with no effect.

Am I missing anything? Or are there any other methods which can give me better results compared to `CALayer`?

Comment: is it glitchy when the borderWith is a whole number too?

Comment: To test I tried borderWidth 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 and 3.0 but I get same glitchy in all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried many solution and end by using `UIBezierPath`.

I create category of `UIView` and add method to make round rect and border.

This is method of that category:

```
- (void)giveBorderWithCornerRadious:(CGFloat)radius borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor andBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    
    //Make round
        // Create the path for to make circle
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        maskLayer.frame = rect;
        maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
        
        // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    
    //Give Border
        //Create path for border
        UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                         byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                               cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        
        borderLayer.frame       = rect;
        borderLayer.path        = borderPath.CGPath;
        borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        borderLayer.lineWidth   = borderWidth;
        
        //Add this layer to give border.
        [[self layer] addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

I get idea of using `UIBezierPath` from this amazing article: [Thinking like a Bézier path](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/)

I get most of code from this two link:

- [UIView category for rounding just the corners which you want, not all like CALayer cornerRadius.](https://coderwall.com/p/rxat4a)
- [How to get a border on UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083418/1365821)

**Note:** This is category method so self represent view on which this method is called. Like UIButton, UIImageView etc.

Comment: This is very nice solution.
I faced weird problem with thin dark outline when rounding corners by `layer.cornerRadius`, and I fixed it by using code snippet you posted. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to use borderColor parameter ;)

Comment: @KamilNomtek.com borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor; is for border color.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a Swift 5 version of @CRDave's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569752/168996) as an extension of UIView:

```
protocol CornerRadius {
    func makeBorderWithCornerRadius(radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat)
}

extension UIView: CornerRadius {

    func makeBorderWithCornerRadius(radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let rect = self.bounds

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                                    byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = rect
        maskLayer.path  = maskPath.cgPath

        // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer

        // Create path for border
        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                                      byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                                      cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        borderLayer.frame       = rect
        borderLayer.path        = borderPath.cgPath
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor   = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth   = borderWidth * UIScreen.main.scale

        //Add this layer to give border.
        self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is [Kamil Nomtek.com's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37984335/3151675) updated to **Swift 3+** and with some refinements (mostly semantics/naming and using a class protocol).

```
protocol RoundedBorderProtocol: class {
    func makeBorder(with radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor)
}

extension UIView: RoundedBorderProtocol {
    func makeBorder(with radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

        // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
        layer.mask = maskLayer

        //Create path for border
        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        borderLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        //The border is in the center of the path, so only the inside is visible.
        //Since only half of the line is visible, we need to multiply our width by 2.
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth * 2

        //Add this layer to display the border
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by CRDave works great but has one flaw: When called multiple times like on size change, it keeps adding layers. Instead previous layers should be updated.
See below for an updated ObjC version. For swift please adapt accordingly.

```
//  UIView+Border.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Border)
- (void)setBorderWithCornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius
                            color:(UIColor *)borderColor
                            width:(CGFloat)borderWidth;
@end

//  UIView+Border.m
#import "UIView+Border.h"

@implementation UIView (Border)
- (void)setBorderWithCornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius
                            color:(UIColor *)borderColor
                            width:(CGFloat)borderWidth {
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;

    //Make round
    // Create the path for to make circle
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                   byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    maskLayer.frame = rect;
    maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;

    // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    //Give Border
    //Create path for border
    UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                     byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    NSString *layerName = @"ig_border_layer";
    CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)[[[self.layer sublayers] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", layerName]] firstObject];
    if (!borderLayer) {
        borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [borderLayer setName:layerName];
        //Add this layer to give border.
        [[self layer] addSublayer:borderLayer];
    }

    borderLayer.frame       = rect;
    borderLayer.path        = borderPath.CGPath;
    borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    borderLayer.lineWidth   = borderWidth;
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I'm going to post a Swift version for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[de.'s answer worked much better for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759640/3411191)  than CRDave's answer.

I had to translate it from Swift, so I thought I'd go ahead and post the translation:

```
extension UIView {
    func giveBorderWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius r: CGFloat, borderColor c: UIColor, strokeWidth w: CGFloat) {
        let rect = self.bounds

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        maskLayer.frame = rect
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer

        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))

        let layerName = "border_layer"
        var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer? = self.layer.sublayers?.filter({ (c) -> Bool in
            if c.name == layerName {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }).first as? CAShapeLayer

        if borderLayer == nil {
            borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            borderLayer!.name = layerName
            self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer!)
        }

        borderLayer!.frame = rect
        borderLayer!.path = borderPath.cgPath
        borderLayer!.strokeColor = c.cgColor
        borderLayer!.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer!.lineWidth = w
    }
}
```

I'm calling the method from `layoutSubviews()`

Answer (score -4):

delete

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.3;
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueMain] CGColor];
```

Comment: That black thin line is not border which I gave. See edited code. I give white thick border to second image and grey border to first one. bot I am getting extra think border around that is my problem.