# iOS - How to Remove UIButton border color?

Tags: ios, uibutton, border

Current button settings

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
button.layer.cornerRadius = 60/2
button.layer.borderWidth = 5
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

It looks like the code above
The problem is, there is a very thin border on the outside as shown in the image below.

[image]

The border color is the same as the `backgroundColor` you set.
Changing `backgroundColor` to red changes the bottom border to red.

I have set `button.layer.shadowColor`.
The button size is 60, and the width / height is set using anchor.

Still searching. But only the borderColor settings.
It is frustrating. Please ask for help. Why does this happen?

Comment: try to remove the shadowColor or setting it clear

Comment: The border is white as expected, but the thin border which is appearing seems to be shadow. So try to remove shadow or clear shadowColor

Comment: Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551053/cornerradius-with-border-glitch-around-border) It may help you

Comment: @Mr.Kushwaha - I did not set the shadow option.
I tried the clear color and it failed.

Comment: @PPL - roundCorners applied. But the button is not showing haha :(

Comment: if button is not showing then how can you say roundCorners applied? :D

Comment: @PPL - using anchor -> widthAnchor.constraint / heightAnchor.constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement UIView extension this way,

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask

        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
}
```

Use it like this,

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
button.roundCorners([.allCorners], radius: 30.0, borderColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 10.0)
```

This will display output like this,

[image]

Above image contains button with white borderColor.

This will be generic solution for all buttons in your applications.

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: roundCorners applied. But the button is not showing

Comment: How button is not showing? can you please elaborate more

Comment: private let connectButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        button.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 30.0, borderColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 5.0)
        return button
    }()

Comment: not using xib, storyboard.
It was written in code.
The place where the button was created is tableViewCell.
I will surely succeed for your efforts. :D

Comment: subclass UIButton and call this method on override func layoutSubviews()

Comment: Thank you!! :D Perfact!! very very nice :) haha

Answer (score 0):

Setting `shadowOpacity` to zero should solve your issue.

```
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

Comment: I did not set the shadow option.
I tried the clear color and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clip a layer's bounds.

```
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I know why there's a line around the button, I met it before. Actually the line is the gap between border and background, `button.layer.border` doesn't draw correctly. You can try to draw a border yourself and cover on the button.

Answer (score 0):

you have to clip the bound and add a blank title

```
 button.clipsToBounds = true
 button.setTitle("  ", for: .normal)
```