# Draw Border on Curve Shape Layer

Tags: ios, swift3, uibezierpath

I have already seen this [How to get a border on UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083229/how-to-get-a-border-on-uibezierpath)

I want to draw border on curve

I have drawn curve with following method

```
func drawCurve(from startPoint: CGPoint, to endPoint: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint) {

    var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: startPoint)
    //        bezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint
    bezierPath.addLine(to: controlPoint)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: endPoint);


    bezierPath = bezierPath.bezierCardinal(withTension: 2.06)
    curveSize = bezierPath.bounds
    let strokeColor = UIColor.white
    if curveLayer != nil {
        curveLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        curveLayer = nil
    }
    curveLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    curveLayer?.lineWidth = 1.0 / self.zoomScale
    curveLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    curveLayer?.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    curveLayer?.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    viewBase.layer.addSublayer(curveLayer!)
}
```

I have try to put

```
    curveLayer?.borderWidth = 1.0
    curveLayer?.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
```

But it doesn't draw border around (In box )

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Idea of Abhishek, I have draw Border On Shape with this code

```
let bazierPath2 = UIBezierPath.init(rect: curveSize)


 curveLayerForGingivalLine = CAShapeLayer()
 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.zPosition = 0.0
 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.lineWidth = 1.0 / self.zoomScale
 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

 let  lineShapeBorder = CAShapeLayer()

 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.addSublayer(lineShapeBorder)

 lineShapeBorder.lineWidth = 1.0 / self.zoomScale
 lineShapeBorder.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
 lineShapeBorder.path = bezierPath.cgPath
 lineShapeBorder.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
 curveLayerForGingivalLine?.path = bazierPath2.cgPath
 viewBase.layer.addSublayer(curveLayerForGingivalLine!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code-

```
lineShapeBorder = CAShapeLayer()
lineShapeBorder.zPosition = 0.0
lineShapeBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
lineShapeBorder.lineWidth = 25
lineShapeBorder.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
lineShapeBorder.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
lineShapeFill = CAShapeLayer()
lineShapeBorder.addSublayer(lineShapeFill)
lineShapeFill.zPosition = 0.0
lineShapeFill.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
lineShapeFill.lineWidth = 20.0
lineShapeFill.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
lineShapeFill.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    // ...
var path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: lineStart)
path.addLine(to: lineEnd)
lineShapeFill.path = path.cgPath
lineShapeBorder.path = lineShapeFill.path
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: We created lineShapeBorder with line width 25 so it is acting as border and added lineShapeFill with line width 20 inside lineShapeBorder so it is acting as main or inner layer.

Comment: Here my  `curveLayer` would be  `lineShapeFill` ?